# Openstreetmaps Custom Tile to PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, openstreetmap, tcpdf

I want to add a map image to a pdf file using TCPDF in PHP.
How can I do this? In addition I want to use a custom tile provider (Mapnik, German Style). Are there any solutions or aproaches to make this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with local mapnik copy and [Nik4](https://github.com/Zverik/Nik4).

You'll need:

1. Install postgresql, postgis, mapnik, Nik4
2. Get Mapnik, German Style, style xml.
3. Upload data for the area you are interested in into postgis (via osm2pgsql)
4. Now you can use Nik4 and Nik4 cgi.

It's a rather hard way, but, there are also good news: you can use Docker [dkiselev/nik4web](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dkiselev/nik4web/) image, with pre-installed postgis, mapnik, nik4 and some other stuff.

```
sudo apt-get install docker

# as root
docker pull dkiselev/nik4web
```

Create container and run it

```
docker run -i -t -P dkiselev/nik4web /bin/bash

#from container 
startup
```

After that open localhost/nik4 and you'll get map with vith 2 styles, for one of the states in Russia. So you'll need to change style and area.

First, change the style

Default style is in the `/home/osm/styles/openstreetmap-carto` subfolder. It's in carto css. So get "German Style", if it's in carto css then compile it with carto.

```
su - osm

# save default compiled osm style
mv styles/openstreetmap-carto/osm.xml styles/openstreetmap-carto/osm-def.xml 

# compile german style
carto german_stye.mml > german_style_mapnik.xml

#replace default osm style
mv -f german_style_mapnik.xml styles/openstreetmap-carto/osm-def.xml
```

If it's distributed already as mapnik rendering rules in xml, replace `styles/openstreetmap-carto/osm.xml`.

And the sencond step is to upload new territory with osm2pgsql. osm2pgsql style file for default osm style (I think German Style use the same one) is `/home/osm/styles/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style`

```
osm2pgsql --create --slim --cache 1000 --number-processes 2 --hstore --style /home/osm/styles/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style --multi-geometry --database gis /path/to/osm/data/for/your/region.pbf
```

Thats all. After you'll start postgresql, apache2 and mapnik (see `/bin/startup`) you'll get your own osm with your own style and with svg, pdf and png export.